# How to get the first part of this basic loop exercise right?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript from the book Eloquent Javascript by Marijn Haverbeke, there is exercise at the end of second chapter(Program Structure). Write a loop that makes seven calls to console.log to output the following triangle:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

I tried to solve it like using a for loop.

```
var hash = "#";

for(counter = 0; counter < 8; counter ++)
{

   hash = hash + "#";

   console.log(hash);

}
```

The problem is it's showing not showing the first line of the required output, how do I get that?

I would greatly appreciate any solution especially if it comes with a little explanation.

Comment: This is one of those few noob questions I am willing to upvote purely on the grounds that you asked it properly. It clearly shows the question, the problem, the attempt, and the actual output versus expect. Please don't downvote well asked questions -- close if needed, but don't downvote.

Comment: Welcome to the JS crew. Definitely accept gimbel0893's answer. Declaring the variable as an empty string is the way to go.

Comment: Good job, @Mohil, welcome to StackOverflow! One minor suggestion: usually, you want loop variables to be local, so `for(var counter...` would be better.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I agree this was well asked, but still... a little debugging would have shown the problem.

Comment: Please upvote questions that are _useful_ or at least show research effort, not just questions that are well asked. For questions that aren't well asked, there are downvotes. Do you want this to be the first Google result when someone seaches for "Understanding the for loop in Program Structure"?

Comment: @SterlingArcher did you upvote just because there had been a downvote cast? That would not be OK.

Comment: In my understanding it is ok to upvote for any reason at all (with the possible exception of certain serial upvoting)

Comment: @Vality The acceptable reasons for upvoting appear when you mouse over the upvote arrow.  They are wide open to interpretation, but it is not "you can upvote for any reason at all".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is being executed 'top to bottom'.

In your 'for loop' the first iteration adds an # to the already declared var hash and that makes it ## and this gets 'logged' by the console.

All you need to do is put the console.log(hash) before the hash = hash + "#".

```
console.log(hash);
hash = hash + "#";
```

This will make sure that in the first iteration, first of all a '#' will be 'logged' and only then hash = hash + "#" will get to work :)

Comment: But I would add that perhaps you should try to start with an empty string, just like the 'count' should be started from zero, it saves a lot of such 'incidents' :)

Answer (score 12):

Nice job since you're just starting.

You almost got it.  Just declare the variable as an empty string.

```
// this is the line that needs to be changed
var hash = '';

for(....) {
  hash += "#";
  console.log(hash);
}
```

This way as you add to the "hash" variable inside the loop, it doesn't have that extra "#" from variable declaration.

Answer (score 4):

You're immediately concatenating a hash to it. Log out the initial value before the loop.

```
console.log(hash);
for ...
```

Comment: Or initialize hash as empty

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but by doing this you are wasting one character (the 9th one).

initialize like this

```
hash = '';
```

and you are good to go.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = "#"
for(i = 1; i < 8; i++){
    console.log(grid.repeat(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared and initialised the variable, you have to logged it first before you could use the increment or decrement operators like so.

```js
let triangle = '#';
for(counter = 0; counter < 7; counter ++)
{
   console.log(triangle);
   triangle += "#";
}
```

this way console.log() will log in the first hash than increment it to log the rest of the hashes. you should also use the *let* keyword instead of *var* keyword because it introduces block scope that allows us to write clean and less error-prone code.